# CORS blocking fetch function on Nestjs(server) and Vuejs(client) on localhost

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, fetch, nestjs

im try to learn to build my own RestAPI by using node and nest js.
everything works fine, tested on POSTMAN: it works.

but when i tried to fetch it from my frontend, it being blocked by CORS.
although i have enabled the cors setting on Nestjs.

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and calling it from VueJS:

```
postPackageToServer: function () {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

      var raw = JSON.stringify({
        type: "monthly",
        price: 30,
        startDate: "04-08-2020",
        endDate: "06-08-2020",
      });

      var requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: "follow",
      };

      let postData = async() => {
        let postingDating = await fetch("localhost:3000/vouchers", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
      }
    },
```

may i know what i did wrong? and how to fix it.
if this issue has been answered by other question, i would love to learn from it.

thank you

Comment: With your code I get error `URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request`. Try fetching `http://localhost:3000/vouchers` instead (just add protocol).

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that you're only missing the CORS headers in your `fetch` request headers. Try adding this header to your `myHeaders.append()` method:

```
myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your code is ok.

try to add http/https protocol on the client request

try to change cors option

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://example.com',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) 
    choke on 204
}
```